# Ubuntu 16.04 can't activate bluetooth / stopped working

Tags: upgrade, bluetooth

I was using bluetooth fine until it recently stopped working, i.e. I can't activate it through the interface in system settings anymore. I haven't used it in a while, so not sure what is the cause, could be an upgrade.

here are few outputs:

```
$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service  
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-08-06 10:32:32 +07; 31min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 19395 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service   
           └─19395 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
 bluetoothd[19395]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
 bluetoothd[19395]: Starting SDP server
 bluetoothd[19395]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
$ dmesg | grep Blue
[  548.821596] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  548.821618] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  548.821622] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  548.821625] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  548.821629] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  637.237929] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  637.237930] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  637.237933] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

///

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:5534 Standard Microsystems Corp. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04f2:b3ed Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

///

```
$ uname -a
Linux gs-HP-EliteBook-840-G1 4.15.0-29-generic #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 18 08:54:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea how I can get it back?

Also adding the following outputs:

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

///

```
$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             557056  7 bnep
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
```

Comment: Please append the output of `rfkill list`. If your laptop has a hardware switch to disable WiFi and bluetooth, check that it is off. If it has a software switch (often controlled with the blue Fn key), try that.

Comment: just did, no hardware switch (only for wifi) and no software.

Comment: Please append the output of `lsmod | grep bluetooth`. Any chance you disabled it in the BIOS?

Comment: edited the post with the  output.